# How can I access the index and pass that index to a different function in order for me to manipulate that address in a different function

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, caesar-cipher

```
string_location:              db  "Enter string location :", 0
fmt:                          db "%s", 0          ; The printf format, "\n",'0'
fmt_n_end:                    db "%s ", 10, 0          ; The printf format, "\n",'0'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
fmt_scan_char:                db "%s", 0
fmt3:                         db "The result is %c ", 10, 0
fmtS:                         db "%d", 0

        section .bss
input_buffer:                   resd 1
stringarray:                    resq 10
string_location_buffer:         resd 1
init:                   ; initilizing the current array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    mov qword[stringarray+r8], start_msg
    add r8, 8
    cmp r8, 80
    jl init

    mov rdi, stringarray
    call display

ask_message:
        
        mov rdi, string_location
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    
    mov rdi, fmt_scan_char
        mov rsi, string_location_buffer
    xor rax, rax
    call scanf     
        
        xor rax, rax
        xor r8, r8
        xor r9, r9
        mov r9, 8
        
        mov r8b, [string_location_buffer]        ; the first char in the buffer
        sub r8, 48
        
        cmp r8b, 0
        jl ask_message
        
        cmp r8b, 9
        jg ask_message
        
        mov rax, r8
        mul r9
        
        xor rdi, rdi
        mov rdi, [stringarray]     ; move the msg locaton
        xor rsi, rsi
        mov rsi, string_location_buffer
        call caesar
        
        
        jmp main_menu
```

This is my Caesar func

```
    ;; Abdel Nasser YT28615
    ;; This is a basic encryption scheme known as a caesar cipher. 
    ;; The caesar cipher involves shifting every letter in the given 
    ;; string by a given number in the alphabet.

section .data
        shift_value                 db  "Enter shift value: " ,10
        len_sv               equ         $-shift_value
        
        Encryption                  db  "Encryption: "
        len_e                equ         $-Encryption
        
        current_message             db  "current message: ",
        len_cm               equ         $-current_message
        

section .bss
        shift_value_buffer          resb    3
        char_buff                   resb    1

section .text
        global caesar

ask_value:
        xor r8, r8                  ; clears all the registers
        xor r9, r9
        xor r10, r10
        
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, shift_value       ; reads the shift value message                                                                                                         
        mov rdx, len_sv
        syscall
    
        mov rdi, 0
        mov rax, 0
        mov rsi, shift_value_buffer ; takes in  the message from the buffer                                                                                          
        mov rdx, 3
        syscall
    
        mov r8, shift_value_buffer
        mov r9b, [r8]               ; the first char in the buffer
        inc r8
        mov r10b, [r8]              ; the second char in the buffer
        
        cmp r9, 45                  ; if user enters negative number
        je ask_value                ; repormt the user
        
        cmp r10, 10                 ; if the user enter a num with double digits    
        jne double_digit            
        
        sub r9, 48                  ; get the actual num from the asci value
        jmp validate_input          ; validate the input


double_digit:
        xor rcx, rcx
        sub r10, 48                 ; get the acutal num
        sub r9, 48                  ; get the acutal num
    
        mov rax, r9                 ; mov num to multiply in the rax reg
        mov cx, 10                  ; move the num to multiply in cx reg
        mul cx                      ; the multiple to get the first char in the 10s place
        
        add rax, r10                ; add the num in the ones place, the second char inputed
        mov r9, rax                 ; move the shift value from rax into r9 to be validated
    

validate_input:
        cmp r9, 0
        jl ask_value    ; repromts the user for the shift value if its less then 0                                                                                   
    
        cmp r9, 26
        jge ask_value   ; repromts the user for shift vlaue if its greater than 25   
    
        mov r8, r9      ; r8 will hold shift value
        ret
    
print_message:

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, current_message          ; reads out the current message prompt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        mov rdx, len_cm
        syscall

        ;mov rdx, r12 ;                    ; string length to read                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, r10 ; reads out the message the user inputed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        syscall

        ret

caesar:
        xor r10, r10
        mov r10, rdi                   ; moves buffer string in r10 register                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        call ask_value
        call print_message
        
        mov r12, 30

print_Encryption:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, Encryption             ; reads the Encryption string                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        mov rdx, len_e
        syscall

encryption_loop:
        cmp r12, 0                      ; if the counter reaches 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        je save_return                        ; exit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    
        xor r9, r9                      ; clear r9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        mov r9b, [r10]                  ; move the first char in r10 into the first 8 bites of r9
        
        cmp r9, "A"                     ; compares the char in r9 asci value to the asci value of A
        jge upper_case_test             ; if its greater then or equal to A, test if its a upper cas
        jmp update_char                  ; if its under the asic of 65 its not in the alphabet
         
    
upper_case_test:
        cmp r9, 'Z'                     
        jle shift_upper_case1           ; if its less then A and Z ts a Uper case letter
        jmp lower_case_test1
    
shift_upper_case1:
        add r9, r8                          ;add the shift value
        cmp r9, 'Z'
        jg shift_upper_case2
        jmp update_char

shift_upper_case2:
        sub r9, 'Z'
        add r9, "A"-1
        jmp update_char

lower_case_test1:
        cmp r9, 'a'
        jge lower_case_test2            ; if its greater then a, run another test to see if its less then z
        jmp update_char                  ; else print the char, must be a symbol

lower_case_test2:
        cmp r9, 'z'
        jle shift_lower_case1           ; if its less then a and z ts a Uper case letter
        jmp update_char                  ; else print the char since its a not in the alphabet
    
shift_lower_case1:
        add r9, r8                          ; add the shift value
        cmp r9, 'z'                     ; check if it shifts over z
        jg shift_lower_case2            ; if it does wrap around a
        jmp update_char                  

shift_lower_case2:
        sub r9, 'z'                     ; sub the asic value of z 
        add r9, "a"-1                   ; add a to find shift letter
        jmp update_char                  ; then print the char



update_char:
        mov r10b, r9b        ; move that char in the address of char buff                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        mov [char_buff], r9b        ; move that char in the address of char buff                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, char_buff;         // print that char out                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall

update_loop:
        inc r10                     ; get the next char fromt he inputed string
        dec r12                     ; dec the counter
        jmp encryption_loop         ; encrypt the next letter

save_return:
        
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, r10;               // print that char out                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        mov rdx, 40
        syscall
        
        mov rax, r10
        ret
```

I get this error code
[abdelrn1@linux3 PROJECT4] run

```
Message[0]: This is the original message.
Message[1]: This is the original message.
Message[2]: This is the original message.
Message[3]: This is the original message.
Message[4]: This is the original message.
Message[5]: This is the original message.
Message[6]: This is the original message.
Message[7]: This is the original message.
Message[8]: This is the original message.
Message[9]: This is the original message.

Encryption menu options:
s - show current messages
r - read new message 
c - caesar cipher 
f - frequency decrypt 
q - quit program 
Enter option letter ->c
Enter string location :0
Enter shift value: 
1
current message: Encryption: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[abdelrn1@linux3 PROJECT4]
```

I cant even get it to print out the right characters after it gets encrypted.
I know I am not passing in the right address in the char array.
I want it to print the address of the index of the array passed and encrypt it.
I am not too familiar with how to move around in the index of an array. I know i am supposed to mov the array pointer 8*the index I want to access it but i am having trouble doing so.

```
;asm code that calls c function
read_new_msg:
        mov     rdi, enter_msg   ; address to read                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        mov     rax,0            ; or can be  xor  rax,rax                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        call    printf           ; Call C function             
        
        mov rdi, stringarray
        call validate
        
        mov rdi, [rax]
        mov rax, 0
        call printf
        jmp main_menu


// c function
char * validate(char *arr[]){
    char *og_msg = "This is the original message.";
    
    int buffer = 256;
    int position = 0;

    char * cmd = malloc(sizeof(char)* buffer);
    int cha;
    int cont = 1;

    while (cont == 1){
        
        cha = fgetc(stdin);

        if (cha == EOF || cha == '\n'){
            
            // if the second to last char is equal to . or ? or !  
            if (cmd[position-1] == '.' || cmd[position-1] == '!' || cmd[position-1] == '?'){
                free(cmd);      // free the string              
                printf("invalid forget char");
                return og_msg;  // return the basic messsage
            }
            
            // else
            cmd[position] = '\0';   // else set the last char to null terminater
                
            cont = 0;           // end loop

        }
        
        else{
            cmd[position] = cha;
        }
        
        if (position == 0 && cha < 'A' && cha > 'Z'){
            cont = 0;
            free(cmd); // free the string
            printf("invalid capialization");
            return og_msg;
        }

        position++;
        
        // if the string is longer than the buffer size 
        if (position >= buffer){
            buffer += 256;
            cmd = realloc(cmd, buffer); //realloc mem to that string
        }
        

    }

    return cmd;
}

// this is my output I should be able to write something after enter a message
Message[0]: This is the original message.
Message[1]: This is the original message.
Message[2]: This is the original message.
Message[3]: This is the original message.
Message[4]: This is the original message.
Message[5]: This is the original message.
Message[6]: This is the original message.
Message[7]: This is the original message.
Message[8]: This is the original message.
Message[9]: This is the original message.

Encryption menu options:
s - show current messages
r - read new message 
c - caesar cipher 
f - frequency decrypt 
q - quit program 
Enter option letter ->r
Enter new message:
Encryption menu options:
s - show current messages
r - read new message 
c - caesar cipher 
f - frequency decrypt 
q - quit program 
Enter option letter ->
```

I am also not sure why it's not letting me input anything even through I am using fgetc(stdin) to read in each character.

Comment: Use a debugger (such as GDB) to see which instruction segfaults, and look at register values.  See asm debugging tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, especially GDB's `layout reg`.  Your [mcve] isn't very minimal; do some debugging to narrow down which part of your program has a problem.

Comment: All this code and your question is about parameter passing a pointer to an array element at some index?  Look at `leaq`.  Otherwise, need to focus on your making your question clear.